# .xls file corrupted and without template with warning cannot read name?

Tags: excel, maven, jsp, jakarta-ee, jxl

After downloading my .xls file, it brings me data in column but Excel shows me a warning which is:

> office has detected a problem with this file, Editing may harm your
> computer.

The main purpose that I have a file that I need to download based on a prepared template, the version of the jxl that I work with is 2.4.2; the code below works well. I have succeeded to download the file with data but already without the template which defined in my project directory.

```
public class CreaterFileExcel
{

    private static Connection connexion=null;
    private static PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
    private static PreparedStatement pstmt2 = null;
    public  static ArrayList<Date> listeDrmf = new ArrayList<Date>();
    public  static ArrayList<Date> listeJoursFeries = new ArrayList<Date>();
    public static void creerCalendrier(String annee, String versionFac, String versionPrel)
    {
        ResultSet rset = null;
        ResultSet rset2 = null;
        String groupeMen;
        String groupeBim;
        String lot;
        String vague;
        String jourDft;
        String jourDft1;
        String dateDft;
        String dateDft1;
        String jourDrmf;
        String dateDrmf;
        String jourExtraction;
        String dateExtraction;
        String jourPs2;
        String datePs2;
        String jourFacture;
        String dateFacture;

        int delai;
        int drmfType = 0;
        boolean reportPS2 = false;
        String apr = null;
        String bon = null;
        String col = null;
        String men = null;
        String mex = null;
        String idCalFac;
        int lineNumber;
        String groupe;

        String occurence;

    
        Date dateNom;

        Date datePorteFac;


        Date dateValeur;

        int delta;


        int result = 0; 
        String query ="";

        int k = 0;
        int i = 0;
        int w = 9;

        try {

            Locale.setDefault(Locale.FRANCE);
            
            String nomFichierExcel = "D:\\Calendrier"+annee+"-"+versionFac+"-"+versionPrel+".xls"; // Nom du calendrier de sortie
            String filePath = "D:\\IhmFac3107\\ihmfac-calender-war\\CALWAS\\template.xls";          
            WorkbookSettings ws = new WorkbookSettings() ;
            ws.setSuppressWarnings(true);
            Workbook workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File(filePath),ws); 

            WritableWorkbook copy = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File(nomFichierExcel), workbook );

            WritableSheet sheet = copy.getSheet(0); 

            WritableSheet sheet2 = copy.getSheet(1);

            connexion = ServletCalendrier.getConnexion();
            pstmt= connexion.prepareStatement("SELECT idCalFac, groupeMen, groupeBim, dft, lot, vague, drmf, extraction, ps2, dateFacture, delai, drmfType FROM TgCalFac WHERE annee LIKE ? AND versionFac LIKE ? ORDER BY dft, vague");
            pstmt.setString(1, annee);
            pstmt.setString(2, versionFac);
            rset=pstmt.executeQuery();


            Utils.ecrire(sheet,0,3,"Version " + annee + "-" + versionFac + "-" + versionPrel,0,3);
            Utils.ecrire(sheet, 0, 0, annee, 0, 0);

            int j = 9;


            while(rset.next())
            {
                idCalFac = rset.getString("idCalFac");
                groupeMen = rset.getString("groupeMen");
                groupeBim = rset.getString("groupeBim");

                lot = rset.getString("lot");
                vague = rset.getString("vague");

                jourDft = OperationsSurDates.jourSemaine(rset.getDate("dft"));
                dateDft = OperationsSurDates.changeFormatDate(rset.getDate("dft"));

                jourDrmf = OperationsSurDates.jourSemaine(rset.getDate("drmf"));
                dateDrmf = OperationsSurDates.changeFormatDate(rset.getDate("drmf"));

                jourExtraction = OperationsSurDates.jourSemaine(rset.getDate("extraction"));
                dateExtraction = OperationsSurDates.changeFormatDate(rset.getDate("extraction"));

                jourPs2 = OperationsSurDates.jourSemaine(rset.getDate("ps2"));
                datePs2 = OperationsSurDates.changeFormatDate(rset.getDate("ps2"));

                jourFacture = OperationsSurDates.jourSemaine(rset.getDate("dateFacture"));
                dateFacture = OperationsSurDates.changeFormatDate(rset.getDate("dateFacture"));

                delai = rset.getInt("delai");

                drmfType = rset.getInt("drmfType");

                if(vague.equals("A")){
                    lineNumber = 7;
                }else{
                    lineNumber = 8;
                }

                Utils.ecrire(sheet,0,j,groupeMen,0,lineNumber);
                Utils.ecrire(sheet,1,j,annee,1,lineNumber);
                Utils.ecrire(sheet,2,j,groupeBim,2,lineNumber);
                Utils.ecrire(sheet,3,j,lot,3,lineNumber);


                Utils.ecrire(sheet,4,j,jourDft,4,lineNumber);
                Utils.ecrire(sheet,5,j,dateDft,5,lineNumber);


                Utils.ecrire(sheet,6,j,vague,6,lineNumber);

                             .
                             .
                             .
}
```